# Call an object from the first 5 characters, not its full name in R?

Tags: r

I have an object that is called PX557.GGH.WXWX.4986746 (example).

The first 5 characters of this object are unique to this object.

How do i call this object just from the first 5 characters, rather than having to rename it?

Is there a certain character i can add to the end of PX557, that will call this object?

Thanks

Comment: If you use Rstudio, the tab key carries out auto-completion like that. I don't think there's anything similar in the standard R executable

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [`get`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) function, and perform some operations on the character vector returned by `ls`:

```
# create some arbitrary objects
aaa_bbb_ccc <- 'foo'; bbb_ccc_aaa <- 'haz'; ccc_bbb_aaa <- 'mat'
# use substring on ls
get(ls()[substring(ls(), 1, 3) == 'aaa'])

[1] "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be overkill, but here's a helper function that searches for an object using the first few letters, and returns the value if it finds a unique object:

```
rm(list = ls())

g <- function(x) {
  x <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y <- grep(paste0("^", x), ls(envir = globalenv()), value = TRUE)
  if (length(y) > 1) {
    return(message("More than 1 match"))
  } else {
    tryCatch(
      get(y, envir = globalenv()),
      error = function(e) message(paste(x, "not found"))
    )
  }
}

PX557.GGH.WXWX.4986746 <- 123
AB123.GGH.WXWX.4986746 <- 456
PX556.FFG.JKJK.1234567 <- 789
g(PX557)
# [1] 123
g(AB123)
# [1] 456
g(AB1)
# [1] 456
g(AB999)
# AB999 not found
g(PX)
# More than 1 match
```